# Hiding lines when the variance = 0 in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, hide

I have 2 Dimension Tables 2 Facts Table, (POS and SAP)

So I wanted to make comparison if the data in POS is same as SAP
And if POS minus SAP = 0 , I want the whole line hidden

Example as below

| ACCOUNT | POS | SAP | VARIANCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CC100 | 100 | 100 | 0 |
| CC200 |  |  |  |

Then I have a SWITCH measure, Has Discrepancy and All.

However, when Has Discrepancy is selected, only line CC200 is hidden but not CC100 even though the value is 0

Anyone could point out which part I did wrong ?

My working for Variance is as below.

```
inScopeVariance_amount = 

VAR inscopeVamount =
IF(ISINSCOPE(SAP[SAP_Account]),

BLANK() ,

[POS Amount]-[SAP Amount] )

RETURN  

IF(MAX('Date'[Date])<TODAY(),
inscopeVamount,
BLANK()
)
```

and my SWITCH formula as below

```
IF(MAX('Date'[Date])<TODAY(),
SWITCH(
    selectitem,
    "Has discrepancy",
        CALCULATE([inScopeVariance_amount],FILTER(VALUES(POS[ACCOUNT]), [inScopeVariance_amount]<>0)),

    "All",
        [inScopeVariance_amount],
    BLANK()
),
BLANK()
)
```

Comment: Show your sample data from all 4 tables with explaining the relations between tables. Then show your expected output from them with logic. This will help to understand everything clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Is it an acceptable solution to just apply a visual level filter that hides results where the Variance measure is blank or 0?

If you want to avoid specifying a filter on the visual, you need to make sure all measures evaluated for a row you want hidden evaluate to blank - but that is to me more cumbersome than just doing the visual level filter, since you would probably need to double up your DAX code for POS/SAP measures within the Variance measure to avoid circular dependencies.

Comment: Hi, cant apply 0 / Blank in the filter. The whole table will gone missing xD
The data model is built from few tables
POS , SAP, Account Codes, Cost Center, Profit Center.